# How do I make ui text show up in the scene five seconds later and make the ui text disappear eight later unity3d

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine

I having some problems . I need the UI text to show in the scene for at lease six second after and disappear eight later . Here is my code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ssj : MonoBehaviour {

 IEnumerator ShowMessageCoroutine(string message, float timeToShow = 10)
 {
     // Show the text
     text.text = message;

     // Wait for 10 seconds
     float timeShown = 0f;
     while (timeShown < timeToShow)
     {
         timeShown += Time.deltaTime;
         yield return null;
     }

     // Hide the text
     text.text = "";
 }
}
```

Comment: **"show up in the scene five seconds later and make the ui text disappear eight later"** You need to explain this more...What are you trying to do also what is your problem? You put a code but did not say what that code is doing

Comment: The code is suppose to make the text appear five seconds later in the scene and disappear eight seconds later.

Comment: Ok, so what's happening now with the code above? What doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. I got an error .

Comment: Funny but what is the error ? Tell us what the problem is.

Comment: error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `text' and no extension method `text' of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define text anywhere and you did not import the UI namespace with `using UnityEngine.UI;`. Now, if you want to see the time while counting, you can use your `timeShown += Time.deltaTime;` code.

If all you want to do is wait for something seconds then simply use `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeValue);` or  `yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeValue);`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ssj : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text text;
    IEnumerator ShowMessageCoroutine(string message, float timeToShow = 10)
    {
        //Wait for 5 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f);

        // Show the text
        text.enabled = true;
        text.text = message;

        //Wait for 8 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(8f);

        // Hide the text
        text.enabled = false;
        text.text = "";
    }
}
```

Make sure to drag your text to the text slot in the script

The title says that you want to wait 5 seconds, show text, wait for another 8 seconds then hide text, that's what the example above should do. Although it doesn't make sense to me. It is very likely you want to use the second parameter to specify how long to wait before hiding text. If that is the case then do the following:

```
public Text text;
IEnumerator ShowMessageCoroutine(string message, float timeToShow = 10)
{
    // Show the text
    text.enabled = true;
    text.text = message;

    //Wait for specified seconds (timeToShow)
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeToShow);

    // Hide the text
    text.enabled = false;
    text.text = "";
}
```

To call the function:  `StartCoroutine(ShowMessageCoroutine("Hello", 8));`

Comment: No . It didn't work . I can send you the link to the project.

Comment: I drag the text over and still nothing happen.

Comment: You have to call the function. You are not calling it now. Call it from the Start function. `void Start(){StartCoroutine(ShowMessageCoroutine("Hello", 8));}`

Comment: It work this time . Thank you . You are a big help to me.

Comment: The  yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f);

        // Show the text
        text.enabled = true;
        text.text = message;

        //Wait for 8 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(8f);

Comment: Is the 8f is for when it disappear ?

Comment: Is 5f when it appear in the scene.

Comment: I really don't understand the question in your comment. The code is commented to show you what's going on. When the first `ShowMessageCoroutine` function is called, it waits for 5 seconds, then the text is enabled. It waits for  another 8 seconds then disables the text. That's it.

Comment: As for the second ShowMessageCoroutine function in my answer, it will enable the text, wait for the specified time(`timeToShow`) then disables the text. Don't forget to accept answer if your problem is solved.